# Guardar los diferentes valores de una columna en una lista - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando un fichero `.csv` mediante `Python` y `Pandas` y quiero guardar en una lista los diferentes valores que hay en una columna. Se que si hago un `print(set(df['Columna1']))` me los muestra.

El problema es que si hago `xx = set(df['Nombre'])` el resultado sale cómo un diccionario sin `values`, solo `keys`. Similar a esto, `{'Juan','Natalia','Ramona'}` y yo querría `['Juan','Natalia','Ramona']`.

¿Cómo se haría? He intentado emplear `tolist()` pero me da error.

Gracias

Comment: Un set no es lo mismo que una lista. El set elimina duplicados y se muestra entre llaves, en lugar de corchetes. Para pasar a lista la columna será `list(df.columna)`. Si quieres una lista con los valores sin repetir, `list(df.columna.unique())`, o bien `list(set(df.columna))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comentario de @Abulafia resuelve la duda perfectamente.

Un set no es lo mismo que una lista. El set elimina duplicados y se muestra entre llaves, en lugar de corchetes.

Para pasar a lista la columna será `list(df.columna)`. Si quieres una lista con los valores sin repetir, `list(df.columna.unique())`, o bien `list(set(df.columna))`.

Answer (score 0):

Seleccionando la columna que requieres en cuestión y aplicando el método `to_list()` debería funcionar. Cuidado con el nombre del método porque lo has escrito erróneamente.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), 
                  columns=list('ABCD'))

df_a = df['A'].to_list()
```